# how can i setting a 2x3 graphical space to make plots?

Tags: r, package, statistics, modeling, cran

How can I define a graphics space to make plots like the attached figure below using the graphics package in r?

[image: Like this figure]

Comment: `?layout` ; can be used for such layouts. e.g. `lay = layout(rbind(c(0, 1, 0, 0), c(2,3,4,4)))
for(i in 1:4) plot(1)` where a matrix of plot positions is passed. `0` for a blank/no plot, and repeat a number (`4`) to get a larger plot. You can also combine this with reducing the margins, as in alan's answer, to get it how you want it to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
par(mfrow = c(2, 3))
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Then create six plots, of which two are empty:

```
# empty plot
plot.new()

# first plot (top center)
plot(1:10, 1:10)

# empty plot
plot.new()

# second plot (bottom left)
plot(1:10, 1:10)

# third plot (bottom center)
plot(1:10, 1:10)

# fourth plot (bottom right)
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```

[image]